# Functoriality of the $hom$-functor?

Tags: category-theory, programming, functors

(Originally posted on stackoverflow, but I got no satisfying (for me) answer there.)

I'm a bit lost in [Section 8.8 from *Category Theory for Programmers*](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/02/03/functoriality/).

The book reads

> […] the mapping that takes a pair of objects $a$ and $b$ and assigns to it the set of morphisms between them, the $hom$-set $C(a, b)$, is a functor.

I don't understand it. If a functor is something that can be mapped over, what does it mean to map on the mapping […]?

However, I tried to keep reading.

> It is a functor from the product category $C^{op} × C$ to the category of sets, $Set$.

My understanding is that, as long as we talk of objects and not of morphisms, $C^{op} × C$ is not different from $C × C$. Indeed the book addresses that right now:

> Let's define its action on morphisms. […]

and the rest of the paragraph can be made in drawing as follows

```
              a     f    a'
┌┬──────┬┬┬── • <─────── • ──┬┬┬────────┬┐
││      │││                  │││        ││
││C(a,b)│││                  │││C(a',b')││
││  …   │││                  │││   …    ││
││      │││   b     g    b'  │││        ││
└┴──────┴┴┴─> • ───────> • <─┴┴┴────────┴┘
```

where it's clear that $g \cdot h \cdot f$ is in $C(a',b')$ for each $h$ from $C(a,b)$.

However, I can't really match this objects/morphisms/compositions with the statement at the beginning of the section and the one at the very end, therefore I don't get what this $hom$-functor is.

Comment: Are the basic concepts (category, functor, opposite category, product category) clear to you?

Comment: @PaulFrost, I can't answer the question. I _believe_ I've understood what those 4 things are, but I can't avoid thinking that if I had really understood them, than I wouldn't have needed to ask this question. By the way, thank you very much for the edit. I copied it from stackoverflow, where math typesetting is not available.

Comment: "If a functor is something that can be mapped over" - I don't know what this is supposed to mean, but that's not what a functor is. "...what does it mean to map on the mapping" - where does the quote say anything about mapping on the mapping? A functor $C\to D$ is a mapping from objects of $C$ to objects of $D$, and from arrows of $C$ to arrows of $D$, satisfying certain properties. In this case, the hom functor takes an object of $C^{\text{op}}\times C$ (which is a pair of objects of $C$) to an object of $\mathsf{Set}$ (the set of arrows from the first object of $C$ to the second).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\C}{\textsf{C}} \newcommand{\op}{\operatorname{op}} \newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

Lets start with any category $\C$. We want to define the functor $\Hom$ as follows:
$$\Hom: \C^{\op}\times \C \to \textsf{Set}$$
We first need to define it on objects. That's easy: $\Hom(X,Y)$ is by the definition the set of all morphism from $X$ to $Y$.

Next we need to define it on morphisms. But what exactly are morphisms in $\C^{\op} \times \C$? Well for a given pair of objects $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y')$, a morphism $(X, Y) \to (X',Y')$ is actually a pair of morphisms $(f,g)$ where $f:X'\to X$ and $g:Y\to Y'$. Note the direction of arrows due to $\op$. Also you need to understand how composition works in $\C^{\op} \times \C$. If $(f,g)$ and $(f',g')$ are two morphisms then $$(f,g)\circ (f',g'):=(f'\circ f, g\circ g').$$ The different direction again comes from the $\op$.

And so given $(f,g)$ morphism, or equivalently $f$ and $g$ morphisms, we are somehow supposed to create another morphism (which in case of $\textsf{Set}$ is just a function) by going through $\Hom$. Meaning $\Hom(f,g)$ is supposed to be a function $\Hom(X,Y) \to \Hom(X',Y')$. Remember that $\Hom(X,Y)$ is a set, and thus we can consider functions between such sets. There's nothing really deep here. For example if $C(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then we can consider $p:C(\mathbb{R})\to C(\mathbb{R})$ given by $$p(f)(x)=f(x)+1.$$ Meaning it takes any continuous function and applies "$+1$" to it. It is a similar idea here, we are transforming morphisms and such transformation is a function itself.

Anyway how do we define $\Hom(f,g)$? Note that we can evaluate $\Hom(f,g)$ on any $\alpha:X\to Y$. So for a given morphism $\alpha:X\to Y$ we get that $\Hom(f,g)(\alpha)$ is supposed to be an element of $\Hom(X',Y')$, i.e. it is supposed to be a morphism $X'\to Y'$. And so given those four pieces of data we have: $f$, $g$, $\alpha$ and the expected output, there is only one real way to construct such morphism:

$$\Hom(f,g)(\alpha):=g\circ\alpha\circ f.$$

I encourage you to write down every object, morphism and composition to see why exactly it is well defined, and why we need that $\op$ (otherwise the composition is invalid, and actually there's no way to fix that).

---

With this we have that $\Hom$ is a functor. For example composition preserving goes like this:
\begin{align}
\Hom\big((f,g)&\circ(f',g')\big)(\alpha) = \\
&= \Hom(f'\circ f,g\circ g')(\alpha) = \\
&=g\circ g'\circ\alpha\circ f'\circ f= \\
&=g\circ \Hom(f',g')(\alpha)\circ f= \\
&=\Hom(f,g)\big(\Hom(f',g')(\alpha)\big).
\end{align}

Note that $(f,g)\circ (f',g')=(f'\circ f,g\circ g')$ again due to $\op$. This gives us

$$\Hom\big((f,g)\circ(f',g')\big)=\Hom(f,g)\circ \Hom(f',g')$$

because $\alpha$ is arbitrary. Just like in the classical set theory if $f(g(x))=h(x)$ for all $x$ then we write $f\circ g=h$.

Also note that I use "$\circ$" symbol here in three different (but closely related) meanings: as a composition in $\C^{\op}\times \C$, as a composition in $\C$, and as a composition in $\textsf{Set}$.

Comment: I follow most of you're answer, but I'm slightly confused at the beginning. When you write $Hom(X,Y)$, that implies that $X$ and $Y$ are objects in the same category $C$, right? Then you refer to an object $X \times Y$ belonging to $C^{op} \times C$. Can you please clarify this a bit? I understand that $C^{op}$ and $C$ are the same category with morphisms reversed, but still... Maybe it could help if you used the $op$ superscript to refer to objects in $C^{op}$, I believe.

Comment: @Enlico my bad, I dont know why I used "$\times$". This should've been a pair of objects. I fixed the answer. Anyway, yes, $C$ and $C^{op}$ have precisely the same objects with reversed arrows. There's no need to use a separate superscrit, especially since ultimately they all have to belong to the same category for the final composition to make sense.

Comment: Ok, so $X$, $Y$, $X'$, $Y'$ are in general 4 different objects from $C$ (and they're also in $C^{op}$).

Comment: @Enlico yes, exactly.

Comment: About the fact that _a morphism $(X, Y)\to (X',Y')$ is actually a pair of morphisms $(f,g)$ where $f:X'\to X$ and $g:Y\to Y'$_, is it implied by whatever you wrote before, or is it an assumption/choice/hypothesis? I mean, what if I write $D$ instead of $C^{op}$ and I don't tell you that $D = C^{op}$? Would than $f$ still go like $X' \to X$? Or would it go the other direction? I'm afraid I'm getting a bit lost in the starting point of all of this, because most of the rest of your answer _does_ make sense to me.

Comment: In other words, what if instead of $C^{op}$ I pick a category which "happens" to have the same objects as $C$ and "happens" to have all the morphisms reversed?

Comment: @Enlico that's the definition of product category: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category you can pick any categories and perform their product. $C^{op}$ is chosen deliberately for the final construction to work.

Comment: Note that if you replace $C^{op}$ with $C$ then the $g\circ\alpha\circ f$ composition is no longer valid (ends of arrows don't match). And there's no way to fix that in general. That's the reason $op$ is there.

Comment: Is $f: X' \to X$ a morphism in $C$ or in $C^{op}$? My understanding from the text of your answer is that it is a morphism in $C^{op}$, which means a morphism $X \to X'$ exists in $C$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Enlico $C^{op}$ has reversed morphisms. A morphism $f\in Hom{C^{op}}(X,Y)$ is a morphism $f:Y\to X$ taken from $Hom_C(Y,X)$, i.e. $Hom_{C^{op}}(X,Y)=Hom_{C}(Y,X)$ by the definition of $op$.

Comment: $Hom_{C^{op}}(X,Y) = Hom_{C}(Y,X)$. They're sets, so they're equal if they have all the elements in common. However, all elements of the former go from $X$ to $Y$ whereas those from the latter go from $Y$ to $X$. How can they be equal?

Comment: @Enlico note the subscript: elements on the left side are morphisms in $C^{op}$, while elements on the right side are morphisms in $C$. Again: $C^{op}$ is constructed from $C$ by reversing arrows. And "reversing arrows" simply means "from now on a morphism $X\to Y$ will be called a morphism $Y\to X$". There's nothing more to that, there's no "inversing function" or some other weird operation here. It's simply relabelling. It's simply interchanging the source and the target.

Comment: Perhaps you should also refresh the definition of category: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics) Note that it doesn't matter what those objects and morphisms really are. What matters is axioms they satisfy. In particual theres nothing prohibiting $Hom_{C^{op}}(X,Y)$ to be $Hom_C(X,Y)$ or any other set, as long as axioms are satisfied.

Comment: It may be just labelling, but it influences what I can compose and what not. Which is a lot.

Comment: @Enlico composition in $C^{op}$ is reversed as well, i.e. $f\circ g$ in $C^{op}$ is by definition $g\circ f$ in $C$. Well, there's no other choice anyway.

Comment: But that's not what I don't understand. I mean, I do understand that the graphical reverse of `d>` is `<b`. There's something else which I don't understand. For instance I keep not understanding how an arrow can be refersed an still be the same.

Comment: @Enlico I dont think there's more I can do for you here. The whole point of $op$ is to solve the problem of reversed composition $Hom$ induces on the first coordinate. It's a technicality. A morphism $f:X\to Y$ is on one hand in $Hom_{C}(X,Y)$ and on the other hand in $Hom_{C^{op}}(Y,X)$. It plays two roles at the same time.