# Is a category one which contains only two objects and **one** morphism between them?

Tags: category-theory, products

Maybe it is a trivial question, but I'm having a hard time in truly understanding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4000871/304517) answer, so I believe I need to clarify to myself some probably obvious things first.

Given this description

- it contains two objects

  - $a$
  - $b$
- it contains 3 morphisms

  - $id_a: a \to a$
  - $id_b: b \to b$
  - $f: a \to b$

Can it represent a category?

I can see the following

- it has objects
- it has morphisms
- it has identity morphisms for each object
- composition of morphims are morphisms

So I'd say it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that composition is part of the data of a category. So in this case we are given a graph consisting of two vertices $A,B$ and three conveniently labeled directed edges $1_A: A \rightarrow A$, $f:A\rightarrow B$, $1_B:B\rightarrow B$. We **define** composition to be that
$$\begin{align*}
1_A \circ 1_A &= 1_A\\
f \circ 1_A &= f\\
1_B \circ f &= f\\
1_B \circ 1_B &= 1_B
\end{align*}$$
From here on it is straightforward to check that this data indeed satisfies all the axioms of a category (associativity and identity).

This category is important, because it is the *free category with an arrow* in the following sense. Given any category $\mathcal{C}$ an arrow $\widetilde{f}: \widetilde{A} \rightarrow \widetilde{B}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ induces a unique functor
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\{A \xrightarrow{f} B\} & \longrightarrow & \mathcal C\\
A & \longmapsto & \widetilde A\\
B & \longmapsto & \widetilde B\\
f & \longmapsto & \widetilde f
\end{array}$$
Conversely any functor $\{A \xrightarrow{f} B\} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ defines a unique morphism $\widetilde f: \widetilde A \rightarrow \widetilde B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ as the image of $f$. These assignments are mutually inverse, so we can deduce that there is a canonical bijection
$$\operatorname{Fun}(\{A\xrightarrow{f}B\},\mathcal{C}) \cong \operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$$
This makes $\operatorname{Mor}: \mathsf{Cat} \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ a *representable functor*, a concept, which you will either already know or learn soon and which is of utter most importance for category theory.

Comment: Can you please clarify the part _$\widetilde{f}: \widetilde{A} \rightarrow \widetilde{B}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ induces a unique functor_? I see that it maps $A$, $B$, and $f$, to $\widetilde{A}$, $\widetilde{B}$, and $\widetilde{f}$ respectively, so it maps objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms without altering the connections. But what does the first of the 4 lines mean? I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: Given _$\widetilde{f}: \widetilde{A} \rightarrow \widetilde{B}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ induces a unique functor_, I interpret that $\widetilde{A}$, $\widetilde{B}$, and $\widetilde{f}$ are 2 objects and 1 morphism in $\mathcal{C}$. So what do $A$, $B$, and $f$ belong to? A category? The category I'm asking about? And what does $\{A \xrightarrow{f} B\} $ mean?

Comment: Everything from *important* onwards was meant as some Bonus info and is not relevant to your original question. With $\{A\xrightarrow{f}B\}$ I mean the category, which is subject of your question and which I introduce in my first paragraph. *free functor* is just some fancy terminology for having a canonical bijection like the one in my last equation. Sorry for making the answer more complicated than it should, I thought having more info on this category would be nice, but I now realize it might have been to early for this.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's too early. However, you have answered my question. I'll probably come back to your answer when the second part will make more sense to me.

Comment: Thank you. Have fun with learning categories :)