# What is the product of category "2" by itself?

Tags: category-theory, products

Saunders Mac Lane, at page 10 from "Categories for the Working Mathematician" names $\mathbb{2}$ the category object of [a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002528/is-a-category-one-which-contains-only-two-object-and-one-morphism-between-th):

> $\mathbb{2}$ is the category $↻ \to ↻$ with two objects $a$, $b$, and just one arrow $a \to b$ not the identity;

What is $\mathbb{2} \times \mathbb{2}$ like?

My understanding is that it should contain

- 4 objects, $(a,a)$, $(a,b)$, $(b,a)$, $(b,b)$,
- some morphisms. But which morphisms?

  - At least one identity morphism for each of the 4 objects, and they all come from combinations of $id_a$ and $id_b$; one of them, for instance, is $id_{(a,b)} = (id_a,id_b)$.
  - What else? Having called $f$ the only non-identity morphism in $\mathbb{2}$, $f: a \to b$, I can only think of other 5 morphisms:

    - $f_1 = (f,f) : (a,a) \to (b,b)$,
    - $f_2 = (id,f) : (a,a) \to (a,b)$
    - $f_3 = (f,id) : (a,a) \to (b,a)$
    - $f_4 = (id,f) : (b,a) \to (b,b)$
    - $f_5 = (f,id) : (a,b) \to (b,b)$

Is this all? Please also correct me if I've abused the notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An arrow in the product category is a pair of arrows, one from each factor category (that is, $\text{Arr}(C\times D) = \text{Arr}(C)\times \text{Arr}(D)$). Since $\mathbb{2}$ has $3$ arrows, $\mathbb{2}\times\mathbb{2}$ has $3^2=9$ arrows. So yes, you found them all.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, would you mind giving a look at [this other question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4005919/what-morphisms-must-exist-in-a-category-if-the-morphism-between-two-hom-sets-rel)? I guess it's again as simple as this one, but I'm trying to have a firm undrstanding of all fine details before going forward in my readings.

Comment: @AlexKruckman sorry, you're right, I was too hasty and my comment was wrong. However, it's worth pointing out that Enlico didn't actually identify all the morphisms in the product category, since their post only lists six. The reason is that you have to list $(id_a,id_b)$ and $(id_b,id_a)$ separately, since they're distinct.

Comment: @Nathaniel Actually, Enlico says "one identity morphism for each of the 4 objects" (and then gives one example) and then lists 5 other morphisms.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think that's all!

You could also say that the arrows of $2\times 2$ are $f_2,\cdots, f_5$ *plus their compositions*, which will yield $f_1$ as the composition $(f_5\circ f_2)$ or $(f_4\circ f_3)$.