# What morphisms must exist in a category if the morphism between two hom-sets relative to that category's objects exist?

Tags: category-theory, morphism

I'm asking this and other questions in an attempt to tackle [something I'm having a hard time to understand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000823/functoriality-of-the-hom-functor/) from another point of view.

Let's consider a category $C$ with 4 objects, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and some morphisms such that

- $|Hom(a,c)| \ge 1$,
- $|Hom(b,d)| \ge 1$,
- there is a morphism $m$ in $Set$ such that $m: Hom(a,c) \to Hom(b,d)$.

What do the 3 hypothesis above imply as regards the other hom-sets in $C$?

My understanding is that, *at the minumum*, $|Hom(b,a)| \ge 1\ \wedge\ |Hom(c,d)| \ge 1$ must be true, but it's not required that the strict inequality holds, nor that the other hom-sets are not empty.

Furthermore, I believe that the concept of dual/opposite category need not be brought in to answer this question.

Is all the above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's consider a category $C$ with $4$ objects, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$,
> and some morphisms such that
>
> - $|\mathrm{Hom}(a,c)| \ge 1$,
> - $|\mathrm{Hom}(b,d)| \ge 1$,
> - there is a morphism $m$ in $\mathsf{Set}$ such that $m: \mathrm{Hom}(a,c) \to \mathrm{Hom}(b,d)$.

Let's pause and observe that the third hypothesis follows from the second hypothesis (so it doesn't add anything). Assuming $\mathrm{Hom}(b,d)$ is non-empty, we can pick some $f\in \mathrm{Hom}(b,d)$ and define $m: \mathrm{Hom}(a,c) \to \mathrm{Hom}(b,d)$ to be the constant function with value $f$, $m(x) = f$.

> What do the 3 hypothesis above imply as regards the other hom-sets in $C$?

Absolutely nothing.

> My understanding is that, *at the minumum*, $|\mathrm{Hom}(b,a)| \ge 1\ \wedge\ |\mathrm{Hom}(c,d)| \ge 1$ must be true.

Nope, that's not the case. And I'm very curious what your reasoning is - this seems like a  total non sequitur!

For example, $C$ could have exactly six arrows: $\mathrm{id}_a$, $\mathrm{id}_b$, $\mathrm{id}_c$, $\mathrm{id}_d$, $f\colon a\to c$, and $g\colon b\to d$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(b,a)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(c,d)$ are both empty.

Comment: I understand you answer, which tells me that I've not been able to outline the hypothesis in my question, resulting in a non sequitur, as you say. The point is that I've not understood the answer to the linked question, and I'm just trying to find out _what_ is not clear to me in that answer.

Comment: If I added that $m$ is actually $Hom(f,g)$ with $f$ and $g$ two morphisms in $C$, would that imply anything on how $f$ and $g$ can look like?

Comment: @Enlico What does "m is Hom(f,g)" mean?

Comment: I mean, if $m$ is not just _a_ morphism, but _the_ morphism that corresponds through $Hom$ to the pair consisting of $f$ and $g$, these two being morphisms in $C$. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ah! Yes, it makes sense. If $f\in Hom(b,a)$ and $g\in Hom(c,d)$, then the Hom functor produces a function of sets $m=Hom(f,g)\colon Hom(a,c)\to Hom(b,d)$ defined by $m(h)= g\circ h\circ f$. But it doesn't imply anything special about $f$ and $g$ - you can plug any pair of arrows into Hom.

Comment: Ok, but it implies that $C$ must have such morphisms $f: b \to a$ and $g: c \to d$. As in, if $|Hom(b,a)| = 0$, then there's no $f$ such that $Hom(f,g) : Hom(a,c) \to Hom(b,d)$, right? (And this is has nothing to do with $C^{op}$.)

Comment: @Enlico I think what you are saying is this: If the image of the Hom functor contains a function $m\colon Hom(a,c)\to Hom(b,d)$, then there must be some arrow $f\colon b\to a$ and some arrow $g\colon c\to d$ in $C$ so that we can have $m = Hom(f,g)$. That's correct, of course. The role of $C^{op}$ is in the very *definition* of the Hom functor - it captures the "direction reversing" in the first argument of Hom, i.e. the fact that $f$ goes from $\mathbf{b}$ to $\mathbf{a}$ in $C$, but we obtain a map of sets from $Hom(\mathbf{a},c)$ to $Hom(\mathbf{b},d)$

Comment: But if thinking about $C^{op}$ confuses you, you can just as well say "Hom is a bifunctor $C\times C\to \mathsf{Set}$ which is contravariant (direction reversing) in its first argument and covariant (direction preserving) in its second argument". This means exactly the same thing as "Hom is a (ordinary) functor $C^{op}\times C\to \mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: I'd like a clarification on the terminology in your last comment. When you refer to $C \times C \to Set$ you write _bifunctor_; what would be wrong/inaccurate/misleading in saying _functor_ instead? Similarly, when you write $C^{op} \times C \to Set$ you write _functor_; what would be [...] in saying _bifunctor_? In both question I'm assuming that I would still write the details about the "variancy".

Comment: @Enlico A function with two inputs, one from a set $X$ and one from a set $Y$, is the same thing as a function with one input, from the cartesian product $X\times Y$. A bifunctor is a functor which takes two inputs, one from a category $C$ and one from a category $D$. Unraveling the definition, this is the same as a functor which takes one input, from the product category $C\times D$. So the terminology "bifunctor" is redundant. The only advantage to the "bifunctor" terminology is that you can separately specify whether it is covariant or contravariant in each input, as in my comment.

Comment: Now specifying that the bifunctor is contravariant in one input or the other or both is the same as putting an "op" on that category. e.g. a bifunctor contravariant in the $C$ input and covariant in the $D$ input is the same as an ordinary functor from $C^{op}\times D$. A bifunctor which is contravariant in both inputs is the same as an ordinary functor from $C^{op}\times D^{op}$. There are four possibilities altogether.

Comment: (Maybe the key thing to understand first, if you don't already, is that a contravariant functor $C\to E$ is the same thing as a covariant functor $C^{op}\to E$. So in this way, the contravariant/covariant terminology is also redundant.)

Comment: Thank you very much for all these explanations.